# Installing com-enabled .net assembly onto Windows Terminal Server

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, com, terminal-services

I've got a little class library written in VB.NET (MSVS 2010) with "Com visible" and "Register for COM interop" flags enabled. This lib is intended for use on a Windows 2008 terminal server. I've hit 2 problems:

1. Registering my lib on the server. Apparently, calling `regasm.exe
   my_lib.exe /tlb` is not enough. While `regasm` indeed places
   appropriate keys into a registry, calling
   `CreateObject("My_lib_prog_id")` results in a failure. I temporarily
   solved this problem by installing trial version of MSVS2010 on the
   server, running it with elevated privileges and building the lib
   there. And it worked great, until...
2. A COM-client program running as another user tried to call the lib. It failed.

*Edit*: "failed" means that the VBA throws "System cannot find a file specified" exception while doing `Set obj = CreateObject("MyLibProgID")`. It works fine within the same user account the lib was registered by Visual Studio.

I've tried to give read&execute acces to the lib's directory to everyone, but it didn't work... Any ideas, please?

**UPDATE**

The problem arises if the client is run under *any* other user, even if the user has admin privileges.

Comment: "... results in a failure", "...It failed.".  Can you provide any more detail?

Comment: Maybe running fuslogvw will help.

Comment: The log is emply. No failures.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.100).aspx have you registered the dll in the gac? Can you confirm the com reference is available in vba reference list (find *tlb file).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2850st8(v=vs.100).aspx have you signed the dll with a strong key?

Comment: Signed with a strong name - yes. GAC - no, it couses even more problems: even as admin `CreateObject("MyLibProgID")` couses `ActiveX can not create object` exception

Comment: Have you searched the registry to confirm the values are where they should be? You will probably find a difference between your Dev PC and server on the registry entries. How are you distributing the DLL to the terminal server? With out a doubt you have a com registry (DLL Hell) issue.

Comment: Yes, the keys\values are present in both user registries - Developer and Tester. The whole project directory is copied into a local dir with access rights="Everyone"

Answer (score 2):

Ok firstly, I found that there are a number of issues with .net COM dlls interaction with VBA.

Firstly, configuring them in with .net via attributes, so they correctly configured in the registry is important. Make sure the Dll project has been marked Register for COM interop.

Secondly, if you using an MSI project, ensure that the software has been marked "Install all users". MSI projects do a very poor job of removing registry entries, so if you muck up MSI installs, .net version etc your server ends up with "bad registry entries". I end up using regasm.exe to correctly register the component. I've ended up moving to WIX project installs.

Thirdly, you need to ensure that the registry entries are "machine/global" wide, for terminal server, as each users will be running a potentially different set of "registry" entries. If you have setup the namespaces correctly, you should be able to do early binding in VBA, rather than the riskier late binding "CreateObject" calls.  Just make sure the VBA checks for "broken references" during startup.

Forth, I use a very clean VM to test my installations and registry entries, with the help of MS Office VBA References, to confirm the COM parts have registered correctly, so "CreateObject" calls are not going to fail.

Fifth, watch out for the x86/x64 issues with Terminal server and the explicit version of office your running (Office 2010 x64 in particular). You may have to use the compiler flags /86 explicitly if the server is a x64 (Any CPU can be very bad for VBA .net COM objects).

Sixth, Watch out for the way you raise exceptions from .net to COM. Have a look at System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException for the correct approach.

```
From cmd 
c:
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727{or the edition your using}
COPY "\\Distribution Share\{YourCompany}\{Software}\{Edition}\{.net Com DLL name}.dll" "C:\Program Files\{YourCompany}\{Software}\{.net Com DLL name}.dll"
Regasm.exe "C:\Program Files\{YourCompany}\{Software}\{.net Com DLL name}.dll" /u
Regasm.exe "C:\Program Files\{YourCompany}\{Software}\{.net Com DLL name}.dll" /regfile:"C:\Program Files\{YourCompany}\{Software}\{.net Com DLL name}.reg" /codebase
cd C:\WINDOWS\System32\
Regedit.exe /s "C:\Program Files\{YourCompany}\{Software}\{.net Com DLL name}.reg"
```

I then have a really close look at the registry files that are generated to ensure they are in the correct registry hive.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: 1. Yes, I did that. 2. No, I don't use MSI. Just xcopy deployment of the whole project directory and tried to register it manually/with VS help 3. How exactly do I "ensure " it? And no, early binding is not an option. 4. I do not believe 64/32 conundrum is at fault here - it runs perfectly if run in the same user acc it was registered. Also, see update

Comment: My fall back for these issues is to open MS Access/Excel and create a VBA module. I then goto "references" to confirm the .net COM dll reference is correctly available in the list. Sometimes you have to browse to the *.tlb file that's created (NOT THE DLL). If that works correctly in VBA, then CreateObject("Namespace.Class") should work in whatever environment you want, See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/isvvba/thread/3fee8d3d-3a65-4d03-b4c1-a9b55ece1ffc for a quick overview of the technique.

Comment: Yes, the lib is available in the VBA's "References" dialog under both user accounts. However, it was not included there automatically - manual adding was required.

Comment: I created a simple Library and COM class to test the process and discovered the same "ActiveX" exception you're facing, after getting registry information correct. It implies something has changed in the OS since I had this working with a production product. Will investigate further.